# How to modify an existing block of code in Ruby within a call?

Tags: ruby

For sample if I have this class:

```
class Item
   def initialize
      @i = 10
   end
   def value
      @i ++ 1
   end
end

# initialize the class
i = Item.new
```

Is if we call `p i.value` we get 11. Is it possible to modify this call somehow to get 12 when we run it instead of 11?

Comment: Call `i.value` twice? Do you have the ability to just extend the class? You could just change what its `value` method does.

Comment: To be honest I don't understand what the question is (if you want value to return 12, use `@i + 2` instead of `@i + 1`), but I'm pretty sure you meant `+=` instead of `++`. `@i ++ i` is the same as `@i + (+1)`, which is the same as `@i + 1`.

Comment: I cannot change anything within the class. And my task is to make it return 12 instead of 11, by just chaining that one line of code - the print statement

Comment: Ahh, yes! That could work. What about...if value contained multiplication, say @i * 10, so it would return 100 by default, but I would want it to return 110?

Comment: Again...just add stuff the output by adding to `i.value`, i.e. `p i.value + 10`. I don't really get the problem though.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I understand. Do you mean this?

```
class Item
   def initialize
      @i = 10
   end
   def value
      @i += 1
   end
end

i = Item.new
i.value # 11
i.value # 12
i.value # 13
```

Or you want to do metaprogramming?

```
def i.value
   "whatever"
end

#or maybe this?

class Item 
   def value
       "whatever"
   end
end
```

Comment: Need to be able to do this in one line. Basically I need a way to modify the i, before the "value" gets called, and do it all in one line

Answer (score 1):

It is **not possible** to do with the code you posted.

You can do it with the code:

```
class Item
   def initialize
      @i = 10
   end

   def value(j = 1) # use default parameter
      @i ++ j # it's same as @i + j
   end
end

i = Item.new
i.value => 11
i.value 2 => 12
```

OR

```
class Item
   def initialize
      @i = 10
   end

   def i=(value)
     @i = value
   end

   def value
      @i + 1
   end
end
obj = Item.new
obj.i = 11
p obj.value # => 12
```

Answer (score 0):

Chain a call to [succ](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/String.html#method-i-succ)

```
puts i.value.succ
# => 12
```